# how to keep line notes from getting deleted with force push

Tags: git, github

I have a branch/pull request that is being reviewed.  The reviewer added a couple of line notes via github (webfront).  however, in the past when I make code changes related to those line notes, I rebase -i origin/master (squash commits) then force push to that same branch to keep the pull request number ref the same.  However, when doing so the line notes get deleted.

Is there a way to keep the line notes added by the reviewer? (perhaps I should not squash commits - but I like to keep m changes/commits clean without multiple commits)?

Comment: The only identity commits have are their SHA-1 names, and when you rebase them (even without squashing--re-creating a commit is enough) they change their SHA-1 names. Squashing goes further--by removing some commits.  So if github notes are attached to SHA-1 names of commits (and I see no other sensible way to implement this) I'd say you simply can't have both rebasing and stable notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in github. Considering they track branch names for pull requests, they know what commits have been under that branch name over time. It's a rather large oversight on their review tool, and I have never gotten any significant help from github.

Most of the time you luck out and get a 'so and so commented on an outdated diff', but we still see lots of data loss.

Tools like gerrit track this with a Change-Id in the commit message, but gerrit doesn't use branch names on patch reviews.